# List not printing all elements?

Tags: python, list

I'm VERY confused. I have a list:

```
url1 = 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/'
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url1 + str(num)
    url_list=url.split(',')
    print(url_list)
```

with output:

```
['https://example.tumblr.com/page/1']
['https://example.tumblr.com/page/2']
['https://example.tumblr.com/page/3']
['https://example.tumblr.com/page/4']
```

But when I call this `url_list` or `print(url_list)` again later, I only get this:

```
['https://example.tumblr.com/page/4']
```

I am trying to loop through and perform some operations on each page, but when I call the list it's only returning the last element and I have NO idea how to fix this.
I have checked this question already [Parsing from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733903/python-parse-from-list-only-prints-last-item-not-all) and it did not apply nor solve my issue. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that you're actually printing 4 lists there with one entry each, rather than one list with 4 entries. This is because you're:

1. Making a new variable called "url";
2. Making a new variable called "url_list", then setting it to url.split(','), which makes a new list containing ONLY the newest URL; the split isn't doing anything except placing url into a list.

You want to append to a pre-existing list, like so:

```py
url1 = 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/'
url_list = []
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url1 + str(num)
    url_list.append(url)
print(url_list)
```

Comment: Ah. Understood. Thanks - you explained this well

Answer (score 1):

Your `url_list` is not a list of list. It will contain only the url with num of the current iteration only. Change your code to this:-

```
url1 = 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/'
url_list = []
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url1 + str(num)
    url = url.split(',')
    url_list.append(url)
    print(url)
print(url_list)
```

Comment: Hmm. Confusing when i do url_list.type() I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'type'" - This implies it is a list

Comment: @HenriettaShalansky, try writing `type(url_list)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not implementing a list/array you are just making 'url' the last iterated method in your for loop, which is 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/4'.

Firstly, declare url as a list:

```
urlList = []
```

Then you should change your for loop as it follows:

```
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url1 + str(num)
    urlList.append(url)

print(urlList)
```

making it append each new iteration you make to the original url list and then printing it entirely

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work

```
url1 = 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/'
urls = []
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url1 + str(num)
    urls.append(url)
print(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'url_list' is a variable and a variable only contains the last assigned value. So, you have to declare a list and then append the items into it.

Answer (score 1):

which python version are you using?
In case of using 2.7 change

```
print(urls)
```

to

```
print urls
```

Initially turn url into list. Then follow:

```
url_ = 'https://example.tumblr.com/page/'
urls = []
for num in range(1,5):
    url = url_ + str(num)
    url.append(url_)
print(urls)
print(url_)
```

It works...